# How to programmatically interact with an open MS Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to highlight a word(e.g. a custom search function) in an open word document.

I'd like to know if I can make it happen by single clicking the word.

Comment: The question is not completly clear to me. If you want to intercat with a Microsoft Word application from a csharp(C#) program , you can use the COM automation API  
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format text using a document-level customization. Read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b7k14a4.aspx)